# predicting values given a sinusouidal fit

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, time-series, regression

I'm using Python to fit a time series with a sinusoidal function. I found quite a good match and now I want to be able to predict future values.. I'm at lost here.

Here's what I've got:

```
timeSeries = [0.01146, 0.00724, 0.00460, 0.00192, 0.00145, 0.01559, 0.02585, 0.04118, 0.05073, 0.01966, 0.01486, 0.02784]

import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def createSinFromFit(x, freq, amplitude, phase, offset):
    return np.sin(x * freq + phase) * amplitude + offset

def sinRegr(series):
    t = np.linspace(0, 4*np.pi, len(series))
    guess_freq = 1
    guess_amplitude = 3*np.std(series)/(2**0.5)
    guess_phase = 0
    guess_offset = np.mean(series)
    p0=[guess_freq, guess_amplitude, guess_phase, guess_offset]
    fit = curve_fit(createSinFromFit, t, series, p0=p0)
    results = createSinFromFit(t,*fit[0])
    return results

plotThis = sinRegr(timeSeries)
```

This code produces the fitting you see in this picture:

[image: ![pic]https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNdIu.png]

How can I extend the sin function so that it predicts the future points of the series? i.e. how can I have the sine plot span on to the right, beyond the area covered by the 'known' data points?

Comment: What's your actual problem? You have the parameters calculated, you have the function `createSinFromFit` available to calculate `y` for any `x`. That's all you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to distinguish a data timeline (input) and a fit timeline (output).  Once you do that, the approach is fairly clear.  Below I called them `tdata` and `tfit`:

[image]

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

tdata = np.linspace(0, 10)
timeSeries = np.sin(tdata) + .4*np.random.random(tdata.shape)

def createSinFromFit(x, freq, amplitude, phase, offset):
    return np.sin(x * freq + phase) * amplitude + offset

def sinRegr(tdata, series):
    tfit = np.linspace(0, 6*np.pi, len(series))
    guess_freq = .2
    guess_amplitude = 3*np.std(series)/(2**0.5)
    guess_phase = 0
    guess_offset = np.mean(series)
    p0=[guess_freq, guess_amplitude, guess_phase, guess_offset]
    fit = curve_fit(createSinFromFit, tdata, series, p0=p0)   # use tdata to create the fit
    results = createSinFromFit(tfit,*fit[0])                  # use tfit to generate a new curve 
    return tfit, results

tfit, plotThis = sinRegr(tdata, timeSeries)

plt.plot(tfit, plotThis)
plt.plot(tdata, timeSeries, "ro")
plt.show()
```